# How to save and load an observablecollection on app suspend and start?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to figure out how to save observablecollection items when the app is closed or suspended, and then reload them when the app is opened again. This is what I have, but because the methods are static, and are being called from the App.xaml.cs file, the MemoryItems observablecollection requires a reference. So, I don't really understand how to save and update the observablecollection.
I tried to use an instance of the ViewModel in the App.xaml.cs file, but then I get zero items in MemoryItems observablecollection.

```
public ObservableCollection<MemoryItem> MemoryItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MemoryItem>();

public MainPageViewModel()
{           
}

public string MemoryValue
{
   get
   {
       return _memoryValue;
   }
   set
   {
       _memoryValue = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("MemoryValue");
   }
}


public static async Task Serializer()
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("collection.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MemoryItems);                
        await writer.WriteAsync(json);
    }
}

public static async Task Deserializer()
{
    try
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("collection.json");
        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();                    
            MemoryItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MemoryItem>>(json);
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Handle Exception.
    }
}
```

Then in the App.xaml.cs file

```
public async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs args)
{
    SuspendingDeferral deferral = args.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();

    await MainPageViewModel.Serializer();

    deferral.Complete();
 }

public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));

    await MainPageViewModel.Deserializer();

    await Task.CompletedTask;

 }
```

Comment: Are you not getting any serialization exception?

Comment: It won't compile using the static keyword, but if I change to using an instance, the json file is created, but with no items.

Comment: Yeah. Because new instance of viewmodel doesn't have items. Where your viewmodel is actually used? I mean in which view page? There you should listen for resuming and suspending events

Comment: Right, but I thought that I would have to use the events in the app.xaml.cs file for onetime app loading and suspension. I'll try from viewpage tonight. Thank you.

Comment: No you can use in page also like this this. Application.Current.Resuming. Make sure you unregister when you navigate from that page. Or else it will be called every time you resume regardless of which page you are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove the static keywords and handle everything in the viewmodel using the To and From OnNavigatedAsync methods. I don't anticipate a lot of data being restored each time the application starts, and this is working, so as inelegant as it may be, it gets the job done.

```
        private bool newPage = true;

        public override async Task OnNavigatedFromAsync(IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState, bool suspending)
    {
        await Serializer();
    }

    public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        if (newPage == true) 
        {
            await Deserializer();
            newPage = false;
        }
    }


public async Task Serializer()
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("collection.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MemoryItems);
            await writer.WriteAsync(json);
        }
    }
    public async Task Deserializer()
    {
        try
        {
            var folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("collection.json");
            using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                ObservableCollection<MemoryItem> MemoryItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MemoryItem>>(json);

                if(MemoryItems.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in MemoryItems)
                    {
                        var sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append(item.Memory);
                        var fileString = sb.ToString();

                        var memoryItem = new MemoryItem
                        {
                            Memory = fileString
                        };
                        this.MemoryItems.Add(memoryItem);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Memory();
                } 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle Exception.
        }
    }
```